# Как сделать цикл в данных JSON?

Tags: php

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста как правильно в данному случае сделать цикл в данных JSON?

```html
public function getJSON($shedule)
    {

        $json = '{            
              schedule: [{  
                    '.foreach ($shedule as $val) {.' 
                            day:'.$val.',
                                timeRangers: [
                                        {
                                            start:'.$this->morning_work_hours_from.',
                                            end:'.$this->morning_work_hours_before.',
                                        },
                                        {
                                            start:'.$this->afternoon_work_hours_from.',
                                            end:'.$this->afternoon_work_hours_before.'
                                        }
                                    ]
                           '.}.'
                    },
                ]
          }';

  return $json;

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы ручками json формат пишете? делайте массив нужной структуры и просто json_encode($array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если бы все формировали json вручную, мы бы с вами застряли в прошлом десятилетии

```
public function getJSON($shedule){

    $range = [
              ['start' => $this->morning_work_hours_from, 'end' => ....] ,
              ['start' => ...., 'end' => ....]
        ]; 

    $data = array_map(function($s) use ($range){
                 return [
                        'day' => $s,
                        'timeRangers' => $range
                    ];
              }, $schedule);

    $result = ['schedule' => $data];
    return json_encode($result);          
}
```